# Mobile nav menu creates extra space and scroll bar on windows only

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Upon clicking the mobile menu extra space appears on the right of the page causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear.

It appears that `width: 100vw;` on line 126 is causing the issue but changing this also changes the size of the menu item.

After investigating this issue I found it only appears on windows and not on mac(tested in firefox and chrome).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mike43237/pen/gOrQOdE)

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")[0];
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-links")[0];

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
/****************************
PAGE STYLES
***************************/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3125rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.container-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* NAV */
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: none;
    /* width: 100vw; */
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    /* justify-items: first baseline; */
  }
  .container-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .nav-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  /* NAV END*/
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1440px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" />
  <script src="/scripts/navbar.js" defer></script>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-nav">
      <div class="nav-logo">test</div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class="">
    <div class="container row">
      <h2 class="section-title">container 1</h2>
      <p>
        Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="">
    <div class="container row">
      <h2 class="section-title">container 2</h2>
      <p>
        Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why is this happening?**

The reason this is happening is because `100vw` is the *full* width of the viewport, but your page has a vertical scrollbar so the *available* width is actually "viewport width  - scrollbar width". (If you delete the content from the page so that there is no vertical scrollbar, the horizontal scroll doesn't appear).

So for example, if the viewport width is 600px and the scrollbar is 24px, then 100vw is 600px, but the actual space for the menu item is just 576px (600px - 24px) resulting in a scroll bar.

**How to fix it?**

It is rare that `100vw` is really necessary in CSS layouts - `100%` is usually preferable as it takes 100% of the *available* space of its container. So we just need to make sure each of your menu options' containers are also set up correctly. In your case, you need to make just a few changes to the CSS in your `@media (max-width: 600px)` query:

```
.nav-links {
   width: 100%;     /* change from 100vw; */
}
.nav-links li {
  width: 100%;      /* change from 100vw; */
}
.nav-links.active {
  display: block;   /* change from flex (it isn't needed and just affects the display) */
}
.container-nav {
  width: 100%;      /* this was 80% for some reason? */
}
```

**Working Example**

(Note I've changed the media query to `@media (max-width: 800px)` below, so we can see the dropdown menu here in the snippet window without resizing the screen)

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")[0];
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-links")[0];

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
/****************************
PAGE STYLES
***************************/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3125rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.container-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  /* NAV */
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: none;
     width: 100%; 
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    /* justify-items: first baseline; */
  }
  .container-nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .nav-links.active {
    display: block;
  }
  /* NAV END*/
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1440px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-nav">
      <div class="nav-logo">test</div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class="">
    <div class="container row">
      <h2 class="section-title">container 1</h2>
      <p>
        Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="">
    <div class="container row">
      <h2 class="section-title">container 2</h2>
      <p>
        Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
```